# What is the best practice to fetch non-api data in Next.js(deploying through Vercel)

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

I am trying to fetch my own data before rendering my application. Fortunately, **Next.js** provides `getStaticProps()` for fetching data.

I am currently using `fs` module to fetch my data from json file in local directory.

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const rawData = fs.readFileSync('./dataset/test.json');
  const data = modifyData(JSON.parse(rawData));
  return {
    props: {
      data
    }
  }
}
```

But the problem is, for securing my raw data, I didn't push them to the GitHub remote repository. Forgetting this, when I tried to deploy my app through vercel, it couldn't read any data from my GitHub repository as the repository does not contain any data to fetch from...

I don't want to push my raw data to GitHub.

I would like to know

- the best practice to fetch raw data without pushing any of them to the remote repository

If there are some fundamentals of Next.js or any other I missed, please let me know and correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being "serverless", you've got to host your data somewhere, in a [database](https://vercel.com/docs/solutions/databases) or as a [file](https://vercel.com/docs/solutions/file-storage).

Comment: Could you please elaborate it more? I read links you provided and googled some more. It seems like, if I want to use a file as a data, then I should upload it in serverless (such as AWS S3) and fetch it using api in Next.js. Is it right? Before I deep dive into each concepts, I will be happy if I roughly understand the whole process